# Find object from nested array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, angular

I haven an json array with nested array objects i want to fetch particular object by key name. I've tried alot but i need some generic solution.

```
let data = {"role":"http://www.icai.org/xbrl/taxonomy/role/in-ca/DisclosureOfGeneralInformationAboutCompany","facts":{"concept":"in-ca:DisclosureOfGeneralInformationAboutCompanyAbstract","$t":"","facts":[{"concept":"in-ca:DisclosureOfCompanyInformationAbstract","$t":"","facts":[{"concept":"in-ca:NameOfCompany","d2016":"LAKSHMI ENERGY AND FOODS LIMITED"},{"concept":"in-ca:CorporateIdentityNumber","d2016":"L00000CH1990PLC010573"},{"concept":"in-ca:PermanentAccountNumberOfEntity","d2016":"AAACL3147J"},{"concept":"in-ca:AddressOfRegisteredOfficeOfCompany","d2016":"SCO 18  19  1ST FLOOR SECTOR 9 D, MADHYA MARH   CHANDIGARH"},{"concept":"in-ca:TypeOfIndustry","d2016":"Commercial and Industrial"},{"concept":"in-ca:RegistrationDate"},{"concept":"in-ca:CategoryOrSubcategoryOfCompany"},{"concept":"in-ca:WhetherCompanyIsListedCompany"}]},{"concept":"in-ca:DisclosureOfDocumentInformationAbstract","$t":"","facts":[{"concept":"in-ca:DateOfBoardMeetingWhenFinalAccountsWereApproved","d2016":"2016-05-09"},{"concept":"in-ca:PeriodCoveredByFinancialStatements"},{"concept":"in-ca:DateOfStartOfReportingPeriod","d2015":"2014-04-01","d2016":"2015-04-01"},{"concept":"in-ca:DateOfEndOfReportingPeriod","d2015":"2015-03-31","d2016":"2016-03-31"},{"concept":"in-ca:NatureOfReportStandaloneConsolidated","d2016":"Standalone"},{"concept":"in-ca:ContentOfReport","d2016":"Financial Statements"},{"concept":"in-ca:DescriptionOfPresentationCurrency","d2016":"INR"},{"concept":"in-ca:LevelOfRoundingUsedInFinancialStatements","d2016":"Millions"},{"concept":"in-ca:TypeOfCashFlowStatement","d2016":"Indirect Method"},{"concept":"in-ca:DisclosureWebLinkOfCompanyAtWhichAnnualReportIsPlaced"}]},{"concept":"in-ca:DisclosureOfOtherGeneralInformationAbstract","$t":"","facts":[{"concept":"in-ca:DateFromWhichRegisterOfMembersRemainedClosed"},{"concept":"in-ca:DateTillWhichRegisterOfMembersRemainedClosed"},{"concept":"in-ca:NameOfRegistrarAndTransferAgent"},{"concept":"in-ca:AddressAndContactDetailsOfRegistrarAndTransferAgent"},{"concept":"in-ca:WhetherCompanyIsMaintainingBooksOfAccountAndOtherRelevantBooksAndPapersInElectronicForm","d2016":"true"},{"concept":"in-ca:PostalAddressOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingDataAbstract","facts":[{"concept":"in-ca:CompletePostalAddressOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData","d2016":"Lakshmi Energy and Foods Limited Chandigarh-Ludhiana National Highway, at Khamanon, Punjab,"},{"concept":"in-ca:NameOfCityOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData","d2016":"Chandigarh-Ludhiana National Highway, at Khamanon, Punjab,"},{"concept":"in-ca:NameOfStateUnionTerritoryOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData","d2016":"Punjab"},{"concept":"in-ca:PinCodeOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData","d2016":"141801"},{"concept":"in-ca:NameOfDistrictOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData","d2016":"Punjab"},{"concept":"in-ca:ISOCountryCodeOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData","d2016":"IN"},{"concept":"in-ca:NameOfCountryOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData","d2016":"India"},{"concept":"in-ca:PhoneWithSTDISDCodeOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData","d2016":"01628-661800"}]},{"concept":"in-ca:ParticularsOfServiceProviderAbstract","$t":"","facts":[{"concept":"in-ca:NameOfTheServiceProvider"},{"concept":"in-ca:InternetProtocolAddressOfServiceProvider"},{"concept":"in-ca:LocationOfTheServiceProvider"},{"concept":"in-ca:WhetherBooksOfAccountAndOtherBooksAndPapersAreMaintainedOnCloud"},{"concept":"in-ca:AddressAsProvidedByTheServiceProvider"}]}]},{"concept":"in-ca:DisclosureOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAbstract","$t":"","facts":[{"concept":"in-ca:TotalNumberOfProductOrServiceCategory"},{"concept":"in-ca:DescriptionOfPrincipalProductOrServicesCategory"},{"concept":"in-ca:DisclosureOfPrincipalProductOrServicesTable"},{"concept":"in-ca:DisclosureOfPrincipalProductOrServicesLineItems","$t":"","facts":[{"concept":"in-ca:ProductOrServiceCategoryITC4DigitCode","d2016_TypesOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAxis_Prod1":"1006"},{"concept":"in-ca:DescriptionOfProductOrServiceCategory","d2016_TypesOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAxis_Prod1":"Rice and Paddy"},{"concept":"in-ca:TurnoverOfProductOrServiceCategory","d2016_TypesOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAxis_Prod1":"8,784,320,000.00"},{"concept":"in-ca:HighestTurnoverContributingProductOrServiceITC8DigitCode","d2016_TypesOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAxis_Prod1":"10061090"},{"concept":"in-ca:DescriptionOfProductOrService","d2016_TypesOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAxis_Prod1":"Rice and Paddy"},{"concept":"in-ca:UnitOfMeasurementOfHighestContributingProductOrService","d2016_TypesOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAxis_Prod1":"kg"},{"concept":"in-ca:TurnoverOfHighestContributingProductOrService","d2016_TypesOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAxis_Prod1":"8,784,320,000.00"},{"concept":"in-ca:QuantityOfHighestContributingProductOrServiceInUom"}]}]}]}}
```

actually this object has an facts key while i need to fetch data if concept key is matching with the passed key so it should return particular object. if you have any generic solution please share. i have created one solution but that is an dirty one and that may break at some point of time.

```
const getObj = (data, key, subKey) =>{
let obj = {};
key = `:${key}`;
data.forEach((v)=>{
    if(v.facts){
        if(v.facts.length > 0){
            v.facts.forEach((m)=>{
                if(m.facts){
                    if(m.facts.length > 0){
                        m.facts.forEach((n)=>{
                            if(n.facts){
                                if(n.facts.length > 0){
                                    n.facts.forEach((o)=>{
                                        if(o.concept.includes(key)) {
                                            obj = o;
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                                else{
                                    if(n.concept.includes(key)) {
                                        obj = n;
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                if(n.concept.includes(key)) {
                                    obj = n;
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    else{
                        if(m.concept.includes(key)) {
                            obj = m;
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(m.concept.includes(key)) {
                        obj = m;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        else{
            if(v.concept.includes(key)) {
                obj = v;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if(v.concept == key) {
            obj = v;
            return true;
        }
    }
});

let value = "";
if(obj[`i${subKey}`]) value = obj[`i${subKey}`];
else if(obj[`d${subKey}`]) value = obj[`d${subKey}`];
else if(obj[subKey]) value = obj[subKey];

return value;}
```

Please help me out with this

Comment: is `facts` always an array? please add what you request and the result of it.

Comment: I have never so many `forEach` loops nested inside and inside and going deep. Your code needs a lot of cleanups firstly. This code should be slow as of now because taking so much memory.

Comment: @NinaScholz no it might be object if there is no nested array inside it if facts is nested only then we need to search into deep

Comment: `return true` won't terminate the `forEach`. It will process each item in the array.

Comment: Also, please add the inputs and the expected output. You can probably solve this with a simple recursion that traverses the nested object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach with a short circuit.

```js
const
    find = (object, key, value) => {
        if (!object) return;
        if ((object[key] || '').includes(value)) return object;
        let target;
        [].concat(object.facts).some(o => target = find(o, key, value));
        return target;
    },
    data = { role: "http://www.icai.org/xbrl/taxonomy/role/in-ca/DisclosureOfGeneralInformationAboutCompany", facts: { concept: "in-ca:DisclosureOfGeneralInformationAboutCompanyAbstract", $t: "", facts: [{ concept: "in-ca:DisclosureOfCompanyInformationAbstract", $t: "", facts: [{ concept: "in-ca:NameOfCompany", d2016: "LAKSHMI ENERGY AND FOODS LIMITED" }, { concept: "in-ca:CorporateIdentityNumber", d2016: "L00000CH1990PLC010573" }, { concept: "in-ca:PermanentAccountNumberOfEntity", d2016: "AAACL3147J" }, { concept: "in-ca:AddressOfRegisteredOfficeOfCompany", d2016: "SCO 18  19  1ST FLOOR SECTOR 9 D, MADHYA MARH   CHANDIGARH" }, { concept: "in-ca:TypeOfIndustry", d2016: "Commercial and Industrial" }, { concept: "in-ca:RegistrationDate" }, { concept: "in-ca:CategoryOrSubcategoryOfCompany" }, { concept: "in-ca:WhetherCompanyIsListedCompany" }] }, { concept: "in-ca:DisclosureOfDocumentInformationAbstract", $t: "", facts: [{ concept: "in-ca:DateOfBoardMeetingWhenFinalAccountsWereApproved", d2016: "2016-05-09" }, { concept: "in-ca:PeriodCoveredByFinancialStatements" }, { concept: "in-ca:DateOfStartOfReportingPeriod", d2015: "2014-04-01", d2016: "2015-04-01" }, { concept: "in-ca:DateOfEndOfReportingPeriod", d2015: "2015-03-31", d2016: "2016-03-31" }, { concept: "in-ca:NatureOfReportStandaloneConsolidated", d2016: "Standalone" }, { concept: "in-ca:ContentOfReport", d2016: "Financial Statements" }, { concept: "in-ca:DescriptionOfPresentationCurrency", d2016: "INR" }, { concept: "in-ca:LevelOfRoundingUsedInFinancialStatements", d2016: "Millions" }, { concept: "in-ca:TypeOfCashFlowStatement", d2016: "Indirect Method" }, { concept: "in-ca:DisclosureWebLinkOfCompanyAtWhichAnnualReportIsPlaced" }] }, { concept: "in-ca:DisclosureOfOtherGeneralInformationAbstract", $t: "", facts: [{ concept: "in-ca:DateFromWhichRegisterOfMembersRemainedClosed" }, { concept: "in-ca:DateTillWhichRegisterOfMembersRemainedClosed" }, { concept: "in-ca:NameOfRegistrarAndTransferAgent" }, { concept: "in-ca:AddressAndContactDetailsOfRegistrarAndTransferAgent" }, { concept: "in-ca:WhetherCompanyIsMaintainingBooksOfAccountAndOtherRelevantBooksAndPapersInElectronicForm", d2016: "true" }, { concept: "in-ca:PostalAddressOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingDataAbstract", facts: [{ concept: "in-ca:CompletePostalAddressOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData", d2016: "Lakshmi Energy and Foods Limited Chandigarh-Ludhiana National Highway, at Khamanon, Punjab," }, { concept: "in-ca:NameOfCityOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData", d2016: "Chandigarh-Ludhiana National Highway, at Khamanon, Punjab," }, { concept: "in-ca:NameOfStateUnionTerritoryOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData", d2016: "Punjab" }, { concept: "in-ca:PinCodeOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData", d2016: "141801" }, { concept: "in-ca:NameOfDistrictOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData", d2016: "Punjab" }, { concept: "in-ca:ISOCountryCodeOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData", d2016: "IN" }, { concept: "in-ca:NameOfCountryOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData", d2016: "India" }, { concept: "in-ca:PhoneWithSTDISDCodeOfPlaceOfMaintenanceOfComputerServersStoringAccountingData", d2016: "01628-661800" }] }, { concept: "in-ca:ParticularsOfServiceProviderAbstract", $t: "", facts: [{ concept: "in-ca:NameOfTheServiceProvider" }, { concept: "in-ca:InternetProtocolAddressOfServiceProvider" }, { concept: "in-ca:LocationOfTheServiceProvider" }, { concept: "in-ca:WhetherBooksOfAccountAndOtherBooksAndPapersAreMaintainedOnCloud" }, { concept: "in-ca:AddressAsProvidedByTheServiceProvider" }] }] }, { concept: "in-ca:DisclosureOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAbstract", $t: "", facts: [{ concept: "in-ca:TotalNumberOfProductOrServiceCategory" }, { concept: "in-ca:DescriptionOfPrincipalProductOrServicesCategory" }, { concept: "in-ca:DisclosureOfPrincipalProductOrServicesTable" }, { concept: "in-ca:DisclosureOfPrincipalProductOrServicesLineItems", $t: "", facts: [{ concept: "in-ca:ProductOrServiceCategoryITC4DigitCode", d2016_TypesOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAxis_Prod1: "1006" }, { concept: "in-ca:DescriptionOfProductOrServiceCategory", d2016_TypesOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAxis_Prod1: "Rice and Paddy" }, { concept: "in-ca:TurnoverOfProductOrServiceCategory", d2016_TypesOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAxis_Prod1: "8,784,320,000.00" }, { concept: "in-ca:HighestTurnoverContributingProductOrServiceITC8DigitCode", d2016_TypesOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAxis_Prod1: "10061090" }, { concept: "in-ca:DescriptionOfProductOrService", d2016_TypesOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAxis_Prod1: "Rice and Paddy" }, { concept: "in-ca:UnitOfMeasurementOfHighestContributingProductOrService", d2016_TypesOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAxis_Prod1: "kg" }, { concept: "in-ca:TurnoverOfHighestContributingProductOrService", d2016_TypesOfPrincipalProductOrServicesAxis_Prod1: "8,784,320,000.00" }, { concept: "in-ca:QuantityOfHighestContributingProductOrServiceInUom" }] }] }] } };

console.log(find(data, 'concept', 'foo'));
console.log(find(data, 'concept', 'in-ca:DisclosureOfOtherGeneralInformationAbstract'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```